# Получение атрибута сущности при создании запроса JPA

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

Столкнулся с проблемой в использовании JPA. Мне нужно получить записи из таблицы `Request`, у которых `Type` равен названию типа, приходящему в запросе.

В базе данных `Type` является колонкой таблицы `Request`, в которой хранятся строковые значения типов. Класс `Type` является абстрактным и наследуется другими классами.

```
@Table(name = "REQUEST")
public class Request{
    private Type type;

    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    @Type(type = TypeType.FULL_NAME)
        public Type getType() {
            return type;
        }
}

 public abstract class Type {
        private final String name;
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        private final String label;

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }
    }
```

Нужно составить предикат с логикой типа:

```java
CriteriaQuery<Request> cq = builder.createQuery(Request.class);
Root<Request> root = cq.from(Request.class);
builder.like(root.get(Request_.type.name), typeNameFromQuery).
```

Понятно, что такая запись неверна. Я пробовал закостылить поля `join`-ом, но не вышло, т.к. `Type` уже содержится в нужной таблице.

Каким образом можно реализовать подобную логику?

Comment: Вы не можете ставить аннотацию `@Column` на тип.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете ставить аннотацию `@Column` на тип. Но можно поставить аннотацию `@Transient`. Аннотирование `@Transient` от JPA используется для указания того, что поле не должно сохраняться в базе данных.

```
@Table(name = "REQUEST")
public class Request {

    @Transient
    private Type type;


    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

Comment: Возможно, я не совсем ясно выразился. Поле Type сохраняется в БД, в таблице Request. Просто у него нет своей таблицы.

Comment: Выражаться надо правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то Type это enum и тогда можно поставить аннотацию @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) над этим полем и все заработает

Comment: Type - это не совсем enum. Это абстрактный класс, описывающий необходимые поля при создании новых объектов типа `SomeType`. Добавление аннотации не дало какого-либо результата. Как была ошибка `Parameter value [INFO] did not match expected type [..enums.Type (n/a)] `, так она и осталась

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае, когда в базе это varchar, а у вас Type, то тогда вам нужно использовать аннотацию @Convert:

```
@Convert(converter = TypeConverter.class)
private Type type;
```

И отдельно написать реализацию TypeConverter:

```
public class TypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Type, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Type attribute) {
        return type.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Type convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return someMethod();
    }
}
```

где в someMethod() вы реализуете обратную логику парсинга String в Type.

Comment: А если уже стоит аннотация @Type на нужном мне поле?